# Using GET parameter to get a passed variable

Tags: php, html

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
        echo "`<tr>`<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href="viewproject.php?q=$row['pid']">"$row['pname']"</a></td>";

    }
```

I tried echoing `$row['pid']` in `viewproject.php` page using `$_GET['q']`.

However the above code generates the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'viewproject' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: you use double quotes in other double quotes...

Comment: Please read up on how to use [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Specifically your use of quotes is wrong, look at the syntax highlighting in in your code above and you should see where the problem is.

Comment: `echo "<tr><tr>";echo "<td><a href="viewproject.php?q=".$row['pid'].">".$row['pname']."</a></td>";`

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: ggss please check the answer and mark the answer as accepted if it is correct. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
        echo "`<tr>`<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='viewproject.php?q=".$row['pid']."'>".$row['pname']."</a></td>";

    }
```

**Here I have attached sample code in online editor. [Click Here](https://eval.in/552697)**

**You need to check string concatination in php.  [String Concatination Document](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)**

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<tr><tr>";
echo "<td><a href='viewproject.php?q='" . $row['pid'] . "'>" . $row['pname'] . "</a></td>";
```

You need to concat the string with the `$_GET` variables. Otherwise, the variables will be echoed literally, not the values.

Also, use single quotes for HTML element and double quotes for `echo`.